# ActiveRecord includes association back reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I'm creating an ActiveRecord query that looks like this:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where("created_at > ?", Time.zone.now)
```

In my views, I'm looping over the comments for each Post and I'm doing this `comment.post` which creates N+1, 1 for each post find per comment.

So I can do this to do less queries:

```
Post.includes(comments: :post).where("created_at > ?", Time.zone.now)
```

But, doing that, I still have 1 more query than I'd like.
It first does a query to get all the Posts, then a query to get all comments, and then a 3rd query to get all posts for all the comments.

Since I'm already loading the posts in the first query is there a way I can tell ActiveRecord that the post for each comment is already loaded and it should hook up that back reference without doing a 3rd query?